# Saving the Product in Firebase - category undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I just learned Udemy - The Complete Angular Course - Beginner to Advanced has a little problem in Saving the Product in Firebase "category": "undefined"

I use angular version

Angular CLI: 6.0.8

---

```json
"products" : {
        "-LGoVcK9sUP-lzEqXy-1" : {
          "category" : "undefined",
          "imageUrl" : "imageUrl",
          "price" : 12,
          "title" : "title"
        }
```

---

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input ngModel name="title" type="text" id="title" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <label for="price">Price</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        </div>
        <input ngModel name="price" type="number" class="form-control" id="price">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select [ngModel] name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
            {{ c.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
        <input ngModel name="imageUrl" type="text" id="imageUrl" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
```

```ts
constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  create(product) {
    this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }
```

Comment: How does the `categories$` observable look like? Add this code please.

Comment: like this 

`export class CategoryService {

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  getCategories() {
    return this.db.list('/categories', ref => ref.orderByChild('name')
    ).valueChanges();
  }
}`

Comment: and like this `export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;

  constructor(
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}`

Comment: and what version of angularfire2? As of version 5, the $key metadata is not unwrapped automatically with `.valueChanges()`. If you need access to this metadata you need to use `.snapshotChanges()`

Comment: I use the version : `angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11` I will replace using `.snapshotChanges()`

Answer (score 8):

1.in Categoryservice Change valueChanges() to snapshotChanges()
2. in productform.html change c.name to c.payload.val().name.
3. [value]="c.key"

```
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select ngModel name ="category"  id="category" class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
    {{ c.payload.val().name}}
  </option>
</select>
</div
```